# Kotlin equivalent for checking if not null

Tags: android, kotlin

Can below snippet be written in shorter form in Kotlin using `!` or `?` operators:

```
val acct: GoogleSignInAccount?  = result.signInAccount
if (acct != null && acct.displayName != null)
    MagicToast.showSuccess(this, "Account Name: " + acct.displayName)
```

Comment: you can just check the documentation for these kind of questions. It's all explained very well

Answer (score 5):

```
acct?.displayName?.let {
    MagicToast.showSuccess(this, "Account Name: $it")
}
```

Depending on your use case `acct` might be replaced with `result.signInAccount`.